# Searching a regex pattern to find "forbidden" characters

Tags: java, regex, newline, regex-negation

I've googled a lot for it, but I cannot find any solution.
For a school project I need to find unsupported chars unsupported chars in a string.
Allowed is `[A-Z\s]`.

I found out that `Pattern.match()` only checks whether the *whole* string matches the pattern.
So I tried this pattern: `.*[^A-Z\\s].*`

It works as long as you don't have any newline characters in the string. To check them too, i've used `[.\\s]*[^A-Z\\s][.\\s]*` to handle them as well, but now nothing works any more.

What would be the correct regex  for this purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either:

- just invert the match,
- or invert the character class and try and find one character only:

[go around SO bug -- can't quote code right after a list item]

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^A-Z\\s]");
if (p.matcher(input).find())
    // illegal input, bark
```

Yes, `.matches()` is misnamed... Real regex matching in Java is done using `.find()`.

Comment: +1 for your solution but I don't agree with the "real regex matching in Java is done using ´find()´ part. These are just two different methods of Matcher. ´matches´ attempts to match the ´Pattern´against the whole input, ´find´ attempts to match it inside the input. Semantics...

Comment: m) thanks that works. Why didn't I come on that idea? And thanks for the .find() I used ur first suggestion. `if (!Pattern.matches("[A-Z\\s]*", inputstr))`

Comment: @Mena no, not semantics, 35+ years regex practice. Python and Java are the two mainstream regex languages having refused to acknowledge what "regex matching" meant. Witness the number of people _still_ confused by this misnaming.

Comment: @fge I understand your point but the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for `Matcher` is not ambiguous at all.

Answer (score 0):

try `"(?s).*[^A-Z\\s].*"`  it turns on dotall mode. In dotall mode, the expression `.` matches any character, including a line terminator. By default this expression does not match line terminators. See Pattern.API for (?idmsuxU-idmsuxU)